# How to change command prompt (console) window title from command line Java app?

Tags: java, windows, command-line

How to change and update the title of the command prompt window from the java command line application? Every time I run my application, the command prompt window title shows:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - java MyApp`.

I'd like to change and update the window title as the java program runs, for example as wget(win32) updates downloading status in the title: `Wget [12%]`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although I haven't tried it myself, in Windows, one can use the Win32 API call to [`SetConsoleTitle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050(VS.85).aspx) in order to change the title of the console.

However, since this is a call to a native library, it will require the use of something like [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) in order to make the call, and this will only work on Windows 2000 and later.

**Edit - A solution using JNI**

The following is an example of using JNI in order to change the title of the console window from Java in Windows. To implement this, the prerequiste is some knowledge in C and using the compiler/linker.

First, here's result:

[image: Changing the console title from a Java application]
<sub>(source: [coobird.net](http://coobird.net/img/jni-change-console-title.png))</sub>

Disclaimer: This is my first Java application using JNI, so it's probably not going to be a good example of how to use it -- I don't perform any error-checking at all, and I may be missing some details.

The Java program was the following:

```
class ChangeTitle {

    private static native void setTitle(String s);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ChangeTitle");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String title = "Hello! " + i;
            System.out.println("Setting title to: " + title);
            setTitle(title);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the title is changed every 5 seconds by calling the `setTitle` native method in an external native library called `ChangeTitle`.

Once the above code is compiled to make a `ChangeTitle.class` file, the [`javah`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) command is used to create a C header that is used when creating the C library.

**Writing the native library**

Writing the library will involve writing the C source code against the C header file generated by `javah`.

The `ChangeTitle.h` header was the following:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class ChangeTitle */

#ifndef _Included_ChangeTitle
#define _Included_ChangeTitle
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     ChangeTitle
 * Method:    setTitle
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ChangeTitle_setTitle
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Now, the implementation, `ChangeTitle.c`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "ChangeTitle.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_ChangeTitle_setTitle(JNIEnv* env, jclass c, jstring s) {
    const jbyte *str;
    str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, s, NULL);

    SetConsoleTitle(str);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, s, str);
};
```

A `String` that is passed into the native function is changed into an UTF-8 encoded C string, which is sent to the [`SetConsoleTitle` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050(VS.85).aspx), which, as the function name suggests, changes the title of the console.

(Note: There may be some issues with just passing in the string into the `SetConsoleTitle` function, but according to the documentation, it does accept Unicode as well. I'm not too sure how well the code above will work when sending in various strings.)

The above is basically a combination of sample code obtained from [Section 3.2: Accessing Strings](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#4001) of [The Java Native Interface Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html), and the [`SetConsoleTitle` Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050(VS.85).aspx) page from MSDN.

For a more involved sample code with error-checking, please see the [Section 3.2: Accessing Strings](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#4001) and [`SetConsoleTitle` Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050(VS.85).aspx) pages.

**Building the DLL**

The part that turned out to take the most amount of time for me to figure out was getting the C files to compile into an DLL that actually could be read without causing an [`UnsatisfiedLinkError`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html).

After a lot of searching and trying things out, I was able to get the C source to compile to a DLL that could be called from Java. Since I am using MinGW, I found a page form `mingw.org` which [described exactly how to build a DLL for JNI](http://www.mingw.org/node/41).

Sources:

- [The Java Native Interface Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html)

  - [Chapter 2: Getting Started](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html#769) - Details the process using JNI.
- [JNI-MinGW-DLL](http://www.mingw.org/node/41) - Building a JNI DLL on MinGW with gcc.

Comment: Please don't expend all that effort on doing JNI, head on over to https://jna.dev.java.net/. It's a lot easier using JNA than JNI. It's the best thing since Python ctypes.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on your terminal emulator, but essentially it's just printing out control sequences to the console.

Now I'm not clear on what control sequences CMD.EXE responds to (I haven't one available to try this on) but I hear there's a command called [TITLE](http://www.ss64.com/nt/title.html) which sets the title of the window. I tried piping TITLE's output to a file, but apparently, it doesn't actually set the title by outputting control characters. The START command can take a parameter which is title of the window followed by the command to run in the window. So something like

```
cmd TITLE "lovely Application that is in a command window." && "java" MyApp
REM or
start "lovely Application that is java based." java MyApp
```

Personally I would just bundle the whole thing with a shortcut where you can edit the properties such as the current directory, the command, it's parameters, and the window size, style and title (if I remember rightly). Give it a nice icon and people will use it.

Comment: He wants the title to change as the program runs, not just when starting the Java application from the command line interface.

Comment: Yeah I know, so I was telling someone to find the escape sequence for the title change in cmd (which must exist but I can't find it, even in ANSI.SYS), or the asker could use Java.lang.runtime to exec the title command when it's needed. If that works on the same window.

Comment: Unfortunately using Runtime.exec with "title" doesn't work -- at least from what I tried, I wasn't able to get it to work. I suspect it's because Runtime.exec will start a new process separate from the current process running java.exe.

Comment: Exactly. Runtime.exec spawns new process. And yes, I was looking for solution to update title on the fly.

Comment: Using your second method, I keep getting two CL windows. I switched things around and it worked how I wanted. `@ECHO OFF\n
java -jar myprogram.jar start "Ezproxy App" \n 
PAUSE`

Comment: I added the `\n` to show where a new line starts in the commands.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution using JNA:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class SetTitle {

    public interface CLibrary extends Library {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)
            Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "kernel32" : "c"),
                               CLibrary.class);

        boolean SetConsoleTitleA(String title);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.SetConsoleTitleA("Testing 123");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: With modern JNA (net.java.dev.jna) Native.loadLibrary is deprecated in favor of Native.load, and the (CLibrary) cast is redundant. Otherwise great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CLITools](https://github.com/MomoTheSiM/CLITools) Java library

Answer (score -2):

following dlamblin's revelation ;-)
here's a python code. 
note that there are 2 different commands in most programming languages:

- system
- exec

system will issue a system command, exec indeed spawns a new process. thus:

```
C:\>python
>>> import os
>>> os.system("title berry tsakala")
```

which works inside a running program. Just find the java equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. The (stackoverflow) system works!

Comment: Downvoting because this doesn't even come close to answering "how do I change the window title ***IN JAVA***?"