# How to set c console window title

Tags: c++, c, console, header-files, title

How to set the console window title in C?

```
printf("%c]0;%s%c", '\033', "My Console Title", '\007');
```

This works only under linux, not in windows.

Does anybody know a "cross-platform" solution? (of course not `system ( title=blah )`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`windows.h` defines `SetConsoleTitle()`.

You could use that everywhere, and declare your own function for linux platforms that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to this posting: (Which is for Java, but the accepted answer uses JNI [ie a C Native call].

[How to change command prompt (console) window title from command line Java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994273/how-to-change-command-prompt-console-window-title-from-command-line-java-app)

Comment: Shouldn't need Java - the Java in the posting is simply 'wrapping' a C library (JNI).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling [SetConsoleTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to implement a "cross-playform" solution yourself.

For windows 2000+, you can use SetConsoleTitle(), more imformation can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to achieve this in C is to use [windows.h](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) header and use the [SetConsoleTitle function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletitle)

### Simple Script

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() 
{
    HANDLE handleConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTitle("Mini Desktop App"); // Here add the title of the window
    while(1){
        printf("Works as expected\n");
        printf("Press any Key to exit :)\n");
        getch();
        break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```