# How to change command prompt directory to our required directory using java code

Tags: java

For ex:- `C:\Users\nayasano>`  is the default and I want to change that to `C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\CDA\1.30\bin`, It the directory I want to change to this. By using Java code and after that I run some command form my java code.

Please give some solution for this

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the current working directory in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994273/how-to-change-command-prompt-console-window-title-from-command-line-java-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not change the directory,
instead of this you can run your programs by the following code in java class :-

```
try{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\CDA\1.30\bin\run.bat");
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
```