# Can you set WindowTitle in Launch4j where headerType==console?

Tags: windows, window, exe, launch4j

I have a launch4J config where headerType=console.

Console displays nicely with all the console output. But the title of that console window is always the full path to the executable launcher. Is there some way to set the title of that window and if so how?

Eg if I create a batch file with

```
start "This is my Window Title" mylauncher.exe
```

then I will get a console window with *This is my Window Title* as the title. How can I configure Launch4j so the batch file is not required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no setting within launch4j to do that. There is a `windowTitle` option, but the docs say it is for GUI only.

Instead, I think you have a few options. I'm going to assume you are using Windows only since you are using batch and exe files.

Options:

1. Modify the source to launch4j to add a call to the Win32 API function [`SetConsoleTitle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050%28VS.85%29.aspx). You'd essentially want to recompile the **consolehead**  part and then rebuild your executable. They use **Dev-Cpp** for compiling.

   There is a similar project called [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) that has an option for configuring the console title and it uses this method. Maybe the launch4j owners can add this feature if requested, but it wouldn't be too hard to add it in yourself. I have modified the launch4j source before to fix a bug and it was pretty straightforward.
2. Write a JNI library to call the same Win32 function from your java code. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994273/how-to-change-command-prompt-console-window-title-from-command-line-java-app).
3. Instead of writing your own JNI dll, use the [JNA library](https://github.com/twall/jna) to call `SetConsoleTitle` from Java. See an answer in the same link in #2 for an example usage.